# Getting "TypeError: ngModelCtrl.$render is not a function" when upgrading angularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I just upgraded angularjs 
from angularjs 1.2.9 to angularjs 1.2.19
and
angularjs bootstrap version .7 upgraded to .11

I am now getting an that I am not sure about.

here is the error:

> TypeError: ngModelCtrl.$render is not a function

The `$render` error appears to be due to a line in ui-bootstrap-0.11 on line 2201.

```
  $scope.$watch('totalPages', function(value) {
    setNumPages($scope.$parent, value); // Readonly variable

    if ( $scope.page > value ) {
      $scope.selectPage(value);
    } else {
      ngModelCtrl.$render();
    }
  });
}])
```

this has got to be a bug due to my upgrade...anyone have any advice on how I should handle this?

THanks,

dave

Comment: Any chance you can narrow it down to if it's an angular upgrade problem or a bootstrap upgrade problem? (Upgrade only one of them each time and see if the problem dissappears)

Comment: I narrowed the question down to the $render issue. I tried to just upgrade boostrap-ui but that failed (wsod). I also tried to just upgrade angularjs, but also got the wsod. I believe it is due to bootstrap ui though, because it points to that line in the new bootstrap ui library.

Comment: A quick google search for `ngModelCtrl.$render()` shows from the first result that this is a known breaking change as described here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2157

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a similar case, I replaced page attribute with ng-model on pagination directive, that fixed my issue. Can you try that too?

Comment: I left that step out of my answer. Since you picked up my slack I voted for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Jacob pointed out that there was a discussion that I overlooked on this very issue:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2157

To fix my issue all I did was add an ng-model to the pagination directive.
Thanks for your help, everyone.

Answer (score -1):

I changed Directive Name 'pagination' to diffrentName. Then problem was solved.